Confusion about the UCRT, libc++, and Windows development
I tried to get the very new clang 19 working from llvm 19, but I very quickly started getting confused.
First thing I tried was the llvm Windows binaries straight off of the GitHub release, but those are dependent on MSVC, so I wanted to see what other options I had. I found a MinGW toolchain build of llvm 19 that seemed to work, but this build doesn't include gcc, thus the default stdlib is libc++, which I don't mind because as far as I know libc++ is better at modern C++, which is what I am looking for.
Very quickly though, I started getting confused. Checking an executable built with libc++ with Dependency Walker reveals it only depends on the ucrt library and doesn't have any sort of dependency on libc++. I thought ucrt also needs the Visual Studio redist to work, but trying it in a fresh Windows 10 VM, I don't get any errors.
My questions are:

is this behaviour normal?
what exactly IS the UCRT?
should I keep going in this path and try to get it to work just like I want it to, or should I bite the bullet and go with the MSVC compiler or the clang compiler?


UCRT (ucrtbase.dll) is the (new) Microsoft's C runtime. Depending on it is normal (though it's possible to get a version of MinGW that instead depends on the older msvcrt.dll, but I don't see why you'd do so). You don't need to ship it, modern Windows has it installed by default. "thought ucrt also needed the vs redist to work" I don't think it does, but not 100% sure. "didnt have any sort of depedency on libc++" Did you use any C++ library features?

"should i keep going in this path" IMO yes. My hot take is that MSVC is not a good compiler, and it's only popular because of the massive inertia (and so is, to a lesser degree, its ABI), and I'd rather use Clang everywhere (or at least GCC), preferably with MinGW ABI. I also recommend you to check out MSYS2: it has both Clang (a version that uses MinGW by default) and MinGW GCC in it, both libstdc++ and libc++, and a bunch of prebuilt third-party libraries. (installation, compiler flavors).

@HolyBlackCat there are many reasons to use MSVC, like COM and clr and winrt and directX (compiling directX apps with clang is possible but a big pain). even the fact that MSVCRT is installed on windows by default so you may not have to ship it, therefore you get smaller binaries, there is also visual studio (which is the best free IDE on windows) which has better support for MSVC than clang, also clang is sometimes behind on features compared to MSVC and gcc, and MSVC has better support than clang which is important for corporates, it is usually the project that dictates the compiler.

C++ specific, check C++ compiler support for a list of C++ features available in each compiler which could dictate the compiler choice for C++ applications, for example today clang only has partial support for coroutines and modules, and libc++ doesn't implement std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<>> yet

MSVC is quite simple to use, with Visual Studio. You can, if you want, use clang with VS as well (though, it's usually a slightly older version).

@HolyBlackCat ok so, it was my fault because i tested the compiler with an empty main function, i added a simple std::cout and now the libc++ dependency shows up! i also do use msys2 a lot but the msys2 mingw clang package still hasnt been updated so im temporarily stuck just directly downloading a mingw clang build off of github while i wait for the msys2 package to be updated.

@AhmedAEK MSVC is vastly behind on features, it doesn't implement a single (non-trivial) C++23 feature other than deducing this (not counting the library features, since you can use MSVC STL with Clang). Some of the things you listed seem to be usable with Clang in MSVC-compatible mode (directx, winrt, com (the latter even usable with mingw, I believe?)). CLR - yes, seems to be limited to MSVC. I don't understand why you mention MSVCRT, it's an outdated C runtime that MSVC no longer uses (and neither does modern MinGW). If you meant MSVC STL, Clang can use it too.

@HolyBlackCat the process to get any of those working on MSVC is to hit "RUN", while on clang it is is downloading MSVC then generating the files and testing them with visual studio then hacking a bunch of scripts to get clang to find and use MSVC headers and libraries, i am mostly talking about MSVCP and VCRUNTIME, which are part of windows by default, i realize that you can get clang to use that too, it is just a few more scripts you need to hack together, but this means if you need them the default choice is to use MSVC unless your project strictly requires clang.

@AhmedAEK Doesn't VS have a switch in the project settings to switch to Clang? That should work out of the box. (Though admittedly, last time I checked, the setting broke vcpkg integration in msbuild.) As for finding MSVC libs, Clang should do that out of the box with no configuration. (And if you have multiple versions of MSVC installed, running Clang from the respective developer command prompt makes it prefer that version.)

Get your MinGW-w64 LLVM suite for Windows from https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw/releases
As it's based on MinGW-w64 it doesn't depend on any Microsoft redistributables.
There is a choice between MSVCRT and UCRT, but this refers to which Windows API is used.
Traditionally the MinGW-w64 compiler used MSVCRT as runtime library, which is available on all versions of Windows. Choose this for maximum compatibility with older Windows versions.
Since Windows 10, Universal C Runtime (UCRT) is available as an alternative to MSVCRT.
Universal C Runtime can also be installed on certain earlier versions of Windows (see: Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows).
Avoid mixing LLVM with GCC, as they use different standard libraries.
Certainly avoid mixing LLVM and GCC with MSVC.

The last two paragraphs seem to be wrong? Clang can use the same C and/or C++ standard library as either GCC and MSVC, you can freely mix it with one of the two.

You can in theory, but I have seen cases where a library uses malloc() from one standard library and the calling application uses free() from another standard library. Recipe for disaster, or at least unstable/unreliable applications.

Yep, mixing standard libraries is bad. But using Clang entirely with libstdc++ or MSVC STL is fine.

Yes, I publish binaries of GCC+LLVM both using GCC's standard libraries on https://winlibs.com/ and though it works most of the time there are still some people having issues.
